# cut csv and save in array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a csv file, build in this format:

```
| id | keyword   | description   | more ...   |
| 1  | myKeyword | MyDescription | some stuff | 
| 2  |           |               | some stuff | 
| 3  | myKeyword | MyDescription | some stuff |
```

right now, I want to create a small PHP script, which reads only the first three columns and save these afterwards in an array. For that, i looked up `fgetcsv` but that didn't do the trick. Then I tried somehting like this:

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('myFile.csv'));
```

but that wasn't it, either. 
The file i got is pretty messy and this is why I have to check if keywords and descriptions even exists (more like they are not '').

My output array should be something like:

```
$array[0][0] = 1
$array[0][1] = MyKeyword
$array[0][2] = MyDescription

$array[1][0] = 3
$array[1][1] = MyKeyword
$array[1][2] = MyDescription
```

Thank you already in advance

Answer (score 0):

Okay, nevermind, i got it.
I found a pretty good solution in the phpdoc of `fgetcsv`

```
<?php
function get2DArrayFromCsv($file,$delimiter) {
    if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $i = 0;
        while (($lineArray = fgetcsv($handle, 4000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
            for ($j=0; $j<count($lineArray); $j++) {
                $data2DArray[$i][$j] = $lineArray[$j];
            }
            $i++;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $data2DArray;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the CSV line by line, and split the lines by your delimiter, and append the resultant arrays to a result array.

```
array1 = array();
$handle = fopen("file.csv", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    array1 = array_merge(array1, explode('|',$line);
}
}
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first parse everything with:

- using the function [str-getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) using its options (delimiters and enclosure). The "basic" function may not be able to catch the syntax of your csv file as there is no real standard for it.
- or if you think it worths it, using this [parser class](http://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/)

Then, you may either drop the undesired elements of your table or just ignore them. I hope it will help you a bit.